# what are the advantages of using smaller integer types in rust?

Tags: rust

I am learning rust and in the official tutorial, the author assigned the value 5 to a variable like so:

`let x: i32 = 5;`

I thought this was weird as one could use `u8` as the type and the program would run fine. This got me thinking, are there any advantages to using a lower bit number? Is it faster?

Comment: Short answer: It depends (on a lot).
See this answer on C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193425/should-i-prefer-to-use-small-types-of-int-int8-and-int16-in-c-code
There is no implicit integer promotion in Rust but otherwise the situation is very similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main advantage is that they use less memory. A `vector<i32>` with 1 billion elements will use 4GB, while a `vector<u8>` will use 1GB. This can be a significant advantage regardless of speed.

Arithmetic on smaller integer types on modern CPUs is not faster in general. There are some issues with using only part of a register but optimizers will almost certainly resolve these performance problems for you.

When you have a lot of integers and the optimizer can make use of vectorization (for example adding your 1 billion integers in the vector) then smaller types will typically yield better performance, because more of them fit in a SIMD register.

If you use them just as one scalar stack variable like in your example, I highly doubt there will be a difference in 99% of cases. Here other considerations are more important:

- A bigger type will make overflows less likely, maybe you did calculate your maximal possible value wrong.
- For public interfaces bigger types are more future proof.
- Its better to cast from i8 to i32 than the other way round.

Comment: The exception is i128 and u128 which are slower on many common processors

Comment: I would just add that in addition to taking more memory, large arrays of larger integers will often be slower to process. This is because RAM is much slower than the CPU, and programs that operate on large arrays are often limited by the speed of the RAM rather than the speed of the CPU. Smaller integers mean less time spent fetching data from RAM (or storing it, but the limiting factor is usually the fetching).